# Photoshop: change B&W gradient to red-white

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient

In Photoshop, on a transparent layer, I have an area with a black-to-white gradient. I want to turn it to a red-to-white gradient, so that pure black (0,0,0) becomes pure red (255,0,0). In the example below, I would want to turn the top bar into the bottom one.

[image]

I don't want to re-draw anything, since the gradient has a particular shape. I want to modify the existing image. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a solid red layer and make it clipping mask, with blend mode Screen:

[image]

(Not sure about accuracy, but it should help)

Or for exact 255, 0, 0 you can use Gradient Overlay in Blending options:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I chose "Lighten" for the mode, instead of "Screen". I don't know if "Screen" would correctly preserve the relative gray values.

Comment: @MrSparkly yeah both modes seemed to work same for me.